# How to Hide Video view's Seekbar or Progressbar in android

Tags: android

i am doing live streaming and play video in video view. i want to **hide default progress bar of video view** . so i kindly request for my problem if anybody have good solution for my problem please send me.
Thanx in advance.......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is the code which adds the seek bar when using videoview
So if you have used the code below please comment it and then check
whether you still have a seekbar while viewing the video

```
 MediaController mediaController=new MediaController(this);
 mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
 videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 6):

You have to set the media controller as null like this:

`videoView.setMediaController(null);`

Answer (score 2):

videoView.setMediaController(null);

Comment: You should add an explanation as to how this piece of code solves the problem. The code should also be added to a code block.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the SeekBar hidden with the help of following :

```
 public void hidingSeekBar() {

        final int topContainerId1 = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android");
        final SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) mediaController.findViewById(topContainerId1);
        seekbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        final int topContainerId2 = getResources().getIdentifier("time", "id", "android");
        final TextView mEndTime = (TextView) mediaController.findViewById(topContainerId2);
        mEndTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        final int topContainerId3 = getResources().getIdentifier("time_current", "id", "android");
        final TextView mCurrentTime = (TextView) mediaController.findViewById(topContainerId3);
        mCurrentTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // mEndTime, mCurrentTime;
    }
```

P.S:  I got the reference to the MediaController controls here.

Comment: how  to  hide `thumb` of seekbar of mediaController

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `MediaController`, no need to add these lines below

```
MediaController mediaController=new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

Just comment it

```
//MediaController mediaController=new MediaController(this);
//mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
//videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```