# What is this bar? And how do I get rid of it? Android VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

This is a Screenshot of my VideoView.

[image]

What is this bar(green arrow points to it) and how do I get rid of it(set it/null/hide it/invisible)?

Comment: Perhaps your video view isn't fitting the entire screen, or the aspect of the video doesn't match the video view.

Comment: Use Hierarchy View to inspect your UI and find out what you put there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that that is the seek bar? Shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video) are more screenshots

If that is actually the seek bar you can not show it by following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618968/how-to-hide-video-views-seekbar-or-progressbar-in-android).

Basically just don't set the MediaController:

```
videoView.setMediaController(null)
```

Comment: I think that is the right answer, I tried to alternate 

`bringToFront();` between videoview and button

and it is the relative Layout covering the seek bar, now just need to find out how to hide it.

Comment: Okay, found out what it was, the videoview was not aligned with the screensize and the relative layout was covering the seerk bar. Thank you, you got me on the right track.