# Disable progressbar in Expanded controller view

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Is there a way to disable the seekbar in expanded controller view in android Chromecast SDK V3?
Facing an issue with the progress bar seek for LIVE videos. The playback is getting hanged while seeking. This issue is also seen in cast-videosAndroid sample app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like the answer of Ali Naddaf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977862/how-to-remove-progress-bar-from-chromecast-sender-application), if it is your own application, then don't add the progress bar in the first place.

Other developers hide the video view's Seekbar or Progressbar in android by setting the setMediaController to null.

```
videoView.setMediaController(null);
```

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618968/how-to-hide-video-views-seekbar-or-progressbar-in-android) and this ProgressBar [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

Comment: I want to disable the progressbar in expandedcontroller view and not in the videoview. Is there any way to achieve  that